# TextBox with Huge Bounds?

Tags: c#, textbox, picturebox

I have made a collision detection function:

```
private bool collision()
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(player.Bounds))
            {
                if(c.Name == "")
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It works, however, the "player" PictureBox (set to autosize, and the sprites are the exact size: there are no outlying transparent pixels) collides with the TextBox while still being very far away from it. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From both controls bounds (relating to parent control), deduce the screen bounds and then compute intersection:

```
 Rectangle BoundsInScreenCoor = 
   new Rectangle(c.PointToScreen(new Point(c.Left,c.Top),new Size(c.Width,c.Height)) ;
```

Comment: That doesn't work, sorry. Just for reference, it's c.Top, but also, it never intersects with the object even if it's inside of it.

Comment: @Lightt : did you debug with the console the values of the 2 rectangles? Did you compute both c_BoundsInScreenCoor and player_BoundsInScreenCoor ?

Comment: Thanks. Even though the rectangle is a little bit bigger, it is much better!